# Error al iniciar un proyecto en laravel desde localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5, mysql-workbench

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en laravel en windows 10, pero al tratar de iniciarlo desde localhost para poder ejecutar lo que llevo hecho no me deja, me muestra un listado de carpetas cuando coloco la ruta y al entrar en la carpeta public inicia la pantalla principal pero me envía el siguiente error al tratar de ejecutar mi proyecto. Alguien me pudiera dar luz sobre que debo hacer para ingresar sin problemas y ejecutar mi proyecto
[image: inicio de sesion desde localhost]

Answer (score 0):

Que servidor Manejas? Si estas utilizando XAMPP debe de abrir el control de xampp y te mostrara el puerto que deberás trabajar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O desde la consola podrás hacer php artisan serve, después de haber instalado el composer.